# Bootstrap - convert a section of a website which contains images to embed youtube links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to change a section of this website:
https://technext.github.io/infinity/#portfolio

The portfolio section contains images. I would like to replace these images with embed youtube videos.
In addition I would like for the embed videos to all be the same size.

code for the section:

```
<div class="intro-wrap">

    <div class="row narrow section-intro with-bottom-sep animate-this">
        <div class="col-twelve">
            <h3>דוגמאות לפרויקטים</h3>
            <h1>מה עשיתי</h1>           

            <p class="lead">במהלך חיי המוסיקליים יצא לי לשתף פעולה עם לא מעט אמנים במגוון ז'אנרים. הנה כמה דוגמאות</p>              
        </div>          
    </div> <!-- end row section-intro -->           

</div> <!-- end intro-wrap -->      

<div class="row portfolio-content">
    <div class="col-twelve">
        <div id="folio-wrap" class="bricks-wrapper">                    

            <div class="brick folio-item">
               <div class="item-wrap animate-this" src="images/portfolio/gallery/g-shutterbug.jpg" data-sub-html="#01" >    
                  <a href="#" class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/shutterbug.jpg" alt="Skaterboy">                      
                     <div class="item-text">
                        <span class="folio-types">
                                  Web Development
                               </span>
                               <h3 class="folio-title">Shutterbug</h3>                             
                            </div>                                        
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://www.behance.net/" class='details-link' title="details">
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                  </a>
               </div> <!-- end item-wrap -->

                    <div id="01" class='hide'>
                        <h4>Shutterbug</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum Dolor deserunt labore sint officia. Magna et aute enim proident tempor sunt quis nulla voluptate fugiat velit. <a href="https://www.behance.net/">Details</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end folio-item -->

                <div class="brick folio-item">
               <div class="item-wrap animate-this" data-src="images/portfolio/gallery/g-yellowwall.jpg" data-sub-html="#02">    
                  <a href="#" class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/yellowwall.jpg" alt="Shutterbug">                         
                     <div class="item-text">
                        <span class="folio-types">
                                  Marketing
                               </span>
                               <h3 class="folio-title">Yellow Wall</h3>                                
                            </div>                                        
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://www.behance.net/" class='details-link' title="details">
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                  </a>
               </div> <!-- end item-wrap -->

               <div id="02" class='hide'>
                        <h4>Yellow Wall</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum Dolor deserunt labore sint officia. Magna et aute enim proident tempor sunt quis nulla voluptate fugiat velit. <a href="https://www.behance.net/">Details</a></p>
                    </div>                 
                </div> <!-- end folio-item -->

                <div class="brick folio-item">
               <div class="item-wrap animate-this" data-src="images/portfolio/gallery/g-architecture.jpg" data-sub-html="#03" >     
                  <a href="#" class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/architecture.jpg" alt="Explore">                      
                     <div class="item-text">                                                            
                               <span class="folio-types">
                                  Web Design
                               </span>
                               <h3 class="folio-title">Architecture</h3>
                            </div>                                        
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://www.behance.net/" class='details-link' title="details">
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                  </a>
               </div> <!-- end item-wrap -->    

               <div id="03" class='hide'>
                        <h4>Architecture</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum Dolor deserunt labore sint officia. Magna et aute enim proident tempor sunt quis nulla voluptate fugiat velit. <a href="https://www.behance.net/">Details</a></p>
                    </div>               
                </div> <!-- end folio-item -->

                <div class="brick folio-item">
               <div class="item-wrap animate-this"  data-src="images/portfolio/gallery/g-minimalismo.jpg"  data-sub-html="#04" >
                  <a href="#" class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/minimalismo.jpg" alt="Minimalismo">                       
                     <div class="item-text">                                
                               <span class="folio-types">
                                  Web Design
                               </span>
                               <h3 class="folio-title">Minimalismo</h3>
                            </div>                                        
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://www.behance.net/" class='details-link' title="details">
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                  </a>
               </div> <!-- end item-wrap -->

               <div id="04" class='hide'>
                        <h4>Minimalismo</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum Dolor deserunt labore sint officia. Magna et aute enim proident tempor sunt quis nulla voluptate fugiat velit. <a href="https://www.behance.net/">Details</a></p>
                    </div>                     
                </div> <!-- end folio-item -->

                <div class="brick folio-item">
               <div class="item-wrap animate-this"  data-src="images/portfolio/gallery/g-skaterboy.jpg"  data-sub-html="#05" >      
                  <a href="#" class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/skaterboy.jpg" alt="Bicycle">                         
                     <div class="item-text">                                
                               <span class="folio-types">
                                  Branding
                               </span>
                               <h3 class="folio-title">Skaterboy</h3>
                            </div>                                        
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://www.behance.net/" class='details-link' title="details">
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                  </a>
               </div> <!-- end item-wrap -->

               <div id="05" class='hide'>
                        <h4>Skaterboy</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum Dolor deserunt labore sint officia. Magna et aute enim proident tempor sunt quis nulla voluptate fugiat velit. <a href="https://www.behance.net/">Details</a></p>
                    </div>                 
                </div> <!-- end folio-item -->

                <div class="brick folio-item">
               <div class="item-wrap animate-this"  data-src="images/portfolio/gallery/g-salad.jpg"  data-sub-html="#06">       
                  <a href="#" class="overlay">
                    <img src="images/portfolio/salad.jpg" alt="Salad">                       
                     <div class="item-text">                                
                               <span class="folio-types">
                                  Branding
                               </span>
                               <h3 class="folio-title">Salad</h3>
                            </div>                                        
                  </a>
                  <a href="https://www.behance.net/" class='details-link' title="details">
                    <i class="icon-link"></i>
                  </a>
               </div> <!-- end item-wrap -->

               <div id="06" class='hide'>
                        <h4>Salad</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum Dolor deserunt labore sint officia. Magna et aute enim proident tempor sunt quis nulla voluptate fugiat velit. <a href="www.behance.net">Details</a></p>
                    </div>                 
                </div> <!-- end folio-item -->                  

        </div> <!-- end folio-wrap -->
    </div> <!-- end twelve -->
</div> <!-- end portfolio-content -->
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide examples of your code and any code you may have tried. Also, if you haven't read and/or tried any of their code examples with your app, please do so: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/embed/

Comment: I have read it, when I tried using that, the embeds weren't responsive and they were not the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example on how to set that up with Bootstrap. You just follow the same `grid` layout as you normally would, using `.container`/`.container-fluid`, `.row`, and `.col-*`'s. All you will have to do is adjust some CSS (or Bootstrap classes) to style them exactly how you want (I have only added a `style="margin-bottom: 1rem;"` to the first `.row`). Also, keep in mind that the aspect ratio (`16by9`, `4by3`, etc.) will alter the videos sizing as well.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```